# Python-Phantomjs popup is blocked

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

Hello I'm trying to get the data from a popup window in phantomjs.Everything is working perfectly but when the popup window is up and I'm using javascript to fetch the data I'm getting an output saying that there is activated the pop blocker and i have to deactivated to go on... 
i search a lot about this but i didn't find how i can make this happen...

```
baseurl="example.com"
mydriver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
mydriver.get(baseurl)
time.sleep(5)
home=mydriver.window_handles[0]
mydriver.find_element_by_id('button').click()
away=mydriver.window_handles[1]
mydriver.switch_to.window(away)
data = mydriver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
print(data)
```

Comment: Hey, have you found anything?

Comment: @scythargon No,nothing...